# Why some books define Unilateral Laplace Transform from $0^+$ to $\infty$

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing, integral-transforms

I've encountered with three variations of Unilateral Laplace Transform:

1. $$X(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-st} dt$$
2. $$X(s) = \int_{0^-}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-st} dt$$
3. $$X(s) = \int_{0^+}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-st} dt$$

I understand that the 2nd definition (from $0^-$ to $\infty$) uses $0^-$  as the lower limit to include the origin and capture any discontinuity of $x(t)$ at $t = 0$; this is usefull when dealing with singularity functions such as Heaviside unit step $u(t)$ and Dirac delta $\delta(t)$.

**What I don't understand** is why the 3rd definition uses $0^+$ as lower limit. For example, with this definition the transform is "unable to see" the discontinuity of the function $u(t)$, moreover, is "unable to see" at all the function $\delta(t)$.

Furthermore, in my opinion this 3rd definition creates intrinsic contradictions between some properties of the Unilateral Laplace Transform: For example,

$$x(t)=e^{-3t}u(t) \rightarrow x'(t)=-3e^{-3t}u(t)+e^{-3t}\delta(t) $$

$$ X(s) = \mathcal{L}[x(t)]= \frac{1}{s+3}$$
$$\mathcal{L} [x'(t)]= \mathcal{L} [-3e^{-3t}u(t)+e^{-3t}\delta(t)]=\frac{s}{s+3}$$
$$\mathcal{L} [x'(t)]= sX(s)-x(0^+)=\frac{s}{s+3}-x(0^+)=\frac{s}{s+3}-1$$
So, you get two different results depending on the path you chose to compute!

Please explain the reasons behind this 3rd definition.

Comment: You should say the unilateral Laplace transform of $x(t)$ is the bilateral Laplace transform of $x(t) 1_{t > 0}$, this way all the shift/convolution/differentiation theorems work well (in particular the bilateral Laplace transform of $\delta(t)$ is well-defined), and everything stays the same for the Fourier transform (and your question about $1_{t > 0}$ or $1_{t \ge 0}$ becomes secondary)

Answer (score 0):

To define the unilateral Laplace transform of a function $x(t)$,
$$
X(s) := \int_0^\infty x(t) e^{-st} dt
$$
you can use any of those definitions and get the same thing.  But sometimes strange people want to define the unilateral Laplace transform of something other than a genuine function.  Maybe a "fake" function like the delta function $\delta(t)$.  Or, more generally, a measure $\mu$.  Then the definitions
$$
\int_{[0,+\infty)} e^{-st}\;d\mu(t)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\int_{(0,+\infty)} e^{-st}\;d\mu(t)
$$
may not be equal.  So your definition would have to specify which one you mean.

I guess the point of your "I don't understand" part is: you need to learn about distributions and not treat things like $\delta(t)$ as though it were an ordinary function.

Comment: Strange indeed are those who write $\sqrt{-1}$ as $$\Large j$$

Comment: The true point of the problem is that we learn the (unilateral) Laplace transform for solving convolution equation, but the unilateral Laplace transform is unable to explain the Dirac delta, itself necessary for explaining the convolution. Qed, the teachers have to forget about the unilateral Laplace transform as I said above.